# Chart.js - how to disable everything on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js

How can I set the code that there will be no hover effects, hover options, (hover) links etc on chart?

I'm using chart.js. Below is my code, where I set pie chart.

Html..

```
<div id="canvas-holder" style="width:90%;">
    <canvas id="chart-area" />
</div>
```

..and js...

```
$(document).ready(function () {


                var config = {
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: {
                        datasets: [{
                            data: [60,20],
                            backgroundColor: [
                                "#ddd",
                                "#58AC1C"
                            ],

                            label: 'Dataset 1'
                        }],
                        labels: [
                            "Bla1 ",
                            "Bla2 "+
                        ]   
                    },
                    options: {
                        responsive: true
                    }
                };


                window.onload = function() {
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
                    window.myPie = new Chart(ctx, config);
                };      
            });
```

Comment: You wanted to disable hover effect or disable something on hover?

Comment: what about `:hover` for `#chart-area{}`

Comment: I've tried to linked this site to mobile app. It opens ok and it's responsive and everything is fine. The problem is when a "tap" anywhere in the screen.. Then page reloads (basically it opens another one).. If I remove div with #canvas-holder (so the chart isn't displayed) everything is ok.. other text is displayed ok and I can tap anywhere I want and nothing happens..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

```
 showTooltips: false
```

You can also use the following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/TZq6q/298/

Comment: I've added this, but it didn't solve my problem. Example you put in fiddle was useful.. I've customize it for my data and style, and I think that this is it.. I am testing it and so far it looks like I've got what I need. Tnx!

Answer (score 189):

In order to remove all hover `styles/tooltips` from vanilla chart.js:

```js
var myChart = new Chart(canvas, {
    options: {
        tooltips: {enabled: false},
        hover: {mode: null},
    }
    ...
});
```

Chart.js is watching all `mousemove` events on the canvas within which it has instantiated your chart. Setting  hover 'mode' to null seems to override all the ways the canvas looks for matching elements to assign activated `:hover` classes to.

The tooltip event seems separate, so I had to use both lines to make the chart effectively static.

Note, initial animations still work on a chart with these options.

UPDATE: newest Chart.js has re-bundled the way hover is 'listened' for:

```js
var myChart = new Chart(canvas, {
    options: {
        events: []
    }
    ...
});
```

Making the 'events' option an empty list (instead of `['click', 'hover', etc]`) makes the chart `blind'/static` because it will be listening for no events.

Comment: @Pithikos answer updated to reflect newest version I believe

Comment: ugh yes, this is what i needed. chart.js is a perfect example of how documentation can be reasonably thorough and still be bad

Comment: haha thanks! indeed, such excellent documentation and yet for this puny bit of info I had to scour stackoverflow...

Comment: This was the solution I used with the latest version 2.9.3 of chartjs

Comment: events: [] worked for me in charts.js: ^3.8.0 and react-chartjs-2:^4.2.0

Answer (score 4):

Just use:

```
options: {
        events: ["mousemove", "mouseout", "click", "touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend"],
       
    }
```

Just remove one of them, which you want to remove.

```
options: {
        events: ["mouseout", "click", "touchstart", "touchmove", "touchend"],
       
    }
```

Comment: this works in chartjs v3. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

There's another option:

```
        states: {
            hover: {
                filter: {
                    type: 'none',
                }
            },
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

**Version 2023 V4.4.0**

it must be in the "plugins" object:

```
export const options = {
  plugins: {
    ...
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**As of 2020**

Simply put `tooltips: false` in your options object

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
const options = {
    ...
    tooltips:{
      enabled:false
    },
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to disable only the hover background color changing, maintaining tooltips

```
    options: {
    hover: {mode: null},
}
```

If you don't need tooltips you can choose this option

```
    options: {
    tooltips: {enabled: false},
    hover: {mode: null},
}
```

Answer (score -10):

If what you want is prevent any effect when hovering the mouse over any series, you should disable `tooltip` and `hover` state. You can do it like this:

```js
$(function () {

    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        plotOptions: {
         series: {
            states: {
                      hover: {
                          enabled: false
                      }
                  }
          }
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

```css
#reporting {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 55px; 
    right: 20px; 
    font: 12px Arial, Verdana; 
    color: #666;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 300px; min-width: 300px"></div>
<div id="reporting"></div>
```

(Template taken from Highcharts documentation).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is `Highcharts` example. Question explicitly refers to `chartjs`